# Local web service call in Cordova fails with result ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cordova

I am using ASP.Net and building an android app using Cordova 5.1.1. I have created the web service (**services.asmx**) which has a method **appStatus** and I am calling the same in **index.html** page. This works perfectly when I run or publish in my laptop. But once I build and run, I get the file not found error with status 0.

**Ajax Call**

```
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "services.asmx/appStatus",
            method: "POST",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: ajaxSigninSuccess,
            error: ajaxSigninError
        });

        function ajaxSigninSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }

        function ajaxSigninError(response) {
            alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
        }
```

Following is the response text

```
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: null
ontimeout: null
readyState: 4
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: ""
responseURL: ""
responseXML: null
status: 0
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
```

**Error**

```
GET file:///android_asset/www/services.asmx/appStatus net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem about server + client side.
I call server is where your service ASP.Net ("services.asmx") deploy.
Client is your mobile app in device.
1. When your server + client in your computer.
Ex: url service: "http://localhost:8080/services.asmx" then when you call ajax by url 'services.asmx/appStatus' then it will get path of html file(include ajax code) and prepend to url. If html file is "http://localhost:8080/index.html" then url call by ajax will be: "http://localhost:8080/services.asmx/appStatus". I think it working with you.
2. When server deploy in you computer and client running in device (emulator).
Ip address of your computer and emulator in your computer is different.
Your app start with index.html file: "file:///android_asset/www/index.html" and so that url call by ajax will be: "file:///android_asset/www/services.asmx/appStatus" not found any service or file at url.
3. Solutions: call ajax by full url: "http://domain.com/services.asmx/appStatus" or if your server deploy in local then "http://ipaddress:port/services.asmx/appStatus".

Comment: Both index.html and services.asmx is in the same project and is build and deployed as a hybrid application using cordova. I will try with "http://ipaddress:port/services.asmx/appStatus"

Comment: The complete URL does not help as the android URL is  file:///android_asset/www/index.html, which I dont think will give result.